# Error: Decoded digest length 48 does not match expected length for SHA-256 of 32

Tags: android, app.config, sha256, security

Estoy poniendo un archivo network_security_config.xml, en el pongo la sha256 al que quiero conectarme, pero obtengo un error de longitud.
alguien podria ayudarme?

Este  es mi xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/server_cert" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">https:ejemplo.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/server_cert"/>
        </trust-anchors>
        <pin-set expiration="2021-12-31">
            <pin digest="SHA-256">9c8kf8k7ee2bkb9dk81d2e5fofc2ke0c3c88o2k362fed23ko671f4732k113o3o=</pin>
        </pin-set>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

pero cuando compilo me arroja el siguiente eeror

**"C:User\Androidplatforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\network_security_config.xml:14: Error: Decoded digest length 48 does not match expected length for SHA-256 of 32 [NetworkSecurityConfig]
9c8kf8k7ee2bkb9dk81d2e5fofc2ke0c3c88o2k362fed23ko671f4732k113o3o
^
"**

Comment: holaComo obtuviste ese pin?

Comment: @Jorgesys el pin el el sha256 de mi certificado con extencion .der

Answer (score -1, accepted):

el error me era generado porque no estaba ejecutando el comando correcto, por lo tanto el resultado era erroneo.

```
cat server_cert_public_key.pem | openssl rsa -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

al final ese fue el codigo correcto a ejecutar para solicitarlo.

Answer (score 2):

El error que muestras:

> Error: Decoded digest length 48 does not match expected length for
> SHA-256 of 32

indica en idioma español

> Error: la longitud 48 no coincide con la
> longitud esperada para SHA-256 de 32

En realidad la longitud de palabra en bits debería ser de 32, por lo tanto debes asegurar que el valor sea correcto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se de donde obtuviste el valor que especificas como pin pero para obtenerlo puedes ir a el sitio:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/
También podrías solicitarlo a tus compañeros en la empresa donde desarrollas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al obtenerlo lo configuras en tu archivo `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa:

[Configuración de seguridad](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config?hl=es-419#CertificatePinning)

Comment: El valor que especifico en el pin lo obtuve de un certificado que tengo en el servidor.
con el comando ```sha256Certificado``` y este me arroja el valor